# mongo join two collections and use aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

im trying to get only those products for whom no order exists, so each product has an order id, these audit tables were linked to orders, but those orders are now deleted, i need to locate those products with no orders.

I know when doing aggregates if the joining collection has no records its not returning anything as "docs", but how can i get it to return me docs == empty or null only..

```
db.products.aggregate([

    {
        $match: {
            $and: [
                { "docs": { $exists: false } }
            ]                  
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "orders",
            localField: "orderId",
            foreignField: "orderId",
            as: "docs"
        }
    },
   {
        $unwind:
       {
          path: "$docs",
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
       }
   },
   { $limit: 10 }
]).pretty()
```

Comment: remove first `$match` stage, and don't use `$unwind` stage, instead just use `{ $match: { docs: [] } }` after `$lookup` stage

Comment: @turivishal nope that doest seem to work, it flags an error stating unknown  :

Comment: can you show error, or post some example document for both the collections.

Comment: i think i have it working now... i had to add projection after lookup and the the match clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.products.aggregate([

    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "orders",
            localField: "orderId",
            foreignField: "orderId",
            as: "docs"
        }
    },
   
   { $match: { docs: [] },

   { $limit: 10 }
]).pretty()
```